# Salesforce mobile sdk issue

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

I have used salesforce mobile sdk(version 4.3) in my ios native app. In the login screen of salesforce I have changed from production to sandbox environments.While switching the environments I am getting blue screen, after killing the app it is working fine.

I am getting this error :

> INFO com.salesforce `<SFSecurityLockout>`: App requested passcode screen cancel.  Screen is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This is really old version. Current Salesforce Mobile SDK is in version 7.0. Update to that and see if it helps.

Comment: can't we change in the old version i.e in 4.3,Without updating the sdk.

Comment: I don't expect anyone to investigate or dig why this error is happening in that old version.

Comment: thank u very much